# Searching string for different substrings

Tags: python, string, substring

I have a string. I need to know if any of the following substrings appear in the string.

So, if I have:

```
thing_name = "VISA ASSESSMENTS"
```

I've been doing my searches with:

```
any((_ in thing_name for _ in ['ASSESSMENTS','KILOBYTE','INTERNATIONAL']))
```

I'm going through a long list of thing_name items, and I don't need to filter, exactly, just check for any number of substrings.

Is this the best way to do this? It feels wrong, but I can't think of a more efficient way to pull this off.

Comment: Are you searching for exact words `VISA` and `ASSESSMENTS` or any substring?

Comment: You could probably speed things up a bit if your list of possible substrings were a set, but other than that I don't think there's anything wrong with this approach. This is fine and readable. The next step would be serious algorithm design.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, I am looking for either 'ASSESSMENTS', 'KILOBYTES' or one of several other items.

Comment: @kojiro, Thanks. I'll run some speed tests.

Comment: @JoshEnglish I don't know your initial data, but it *could* be worth eliminating substrings *within* the set: for example, if you have `{'foo', 'bar', 'foobaz'}` you can remove `foobaz` from the set.

Comment: I don't think you can find a better solution. Two style suggestions: *Never* use `_` as a variable name when you are *using* it. Use anything else, but `_` means "A variable that I don't care about". In your case you *do* care about it since you are using it. Also you can drop the parentheses around the genexp: `any(sub in thing_name for sub in [...])` instead of `any((...))`.[this works when the genexp is the *only* argument to a function].

Comment: Another thing I'd be curious about is if `str.startswith` and `str.endswith` are significantly faster for finding substrings anchored at the beginning and end. (In particular, since those methods accept a tuple of strings to match.)

Comment: Note that if your text is a word separated text and the substrings are words, then you could do something like `len(set(substrings).intersection(text.split())) > 0`. @kojiro AFAIK `startswith`/`endswith` are *slower* than slicing + comparison since you are only adding overhead of a function call(at least for small substrings). For bigger texts they may be worth(but by the OP examples I doubt they would provide a performance boost).

Comment: A theoretical solution is to build a [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) for the text(takes `O(n)` time and space), then loop over the substrings and check if they appear in the tree(time proportional to the sum of the lengths of the substrings), i.e. a linear algorithm(while your current approach is more "quadratic" in the worst case). Anyway before trying this I'd profile and see if that code is a bottleneck. If it isn't, then keep it simple.

Comment: Thanks, all. I'm calling this one answered, based on timeit tests.

Comment: @Bakuriu, I use _ in this case because I don't care which substring matched, just that any of them match.

Comment: @JoshEnglish You didn't understand what I wanted to say. If you name a variable `_` then this variable shouldn't appear in *any* expression or statement. The only place where it should be written is the assignment. In your case this is *not* true(it appears both in the assignment in the `for` *and* the `in` comparison), hence you shouldn't use `_`. Use `substring` or `sub` instead.

Comment: @Bakuriu, ah. I thought this was from PEP 8, but it's not there. Maybe I picked it up from pylint, which insists on three characters minimum for variable names, but it allows "_".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `re.search` to see if that is faster. Something along the lines of

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('|'.join(['ASSESSMENTS','KILOBYTE','INTERNATIONAL']))
isMatch = (pattern.search(thing_name) != None)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, everyone. As a result of this, I did some timing and found the re solutions to be the fastest in my situation.

I came up with eight different ways of doing this, and taking data from my situation, given the length and number of fields, the RE is fastest. Pre-Compiling the regular expression was the best, and second best was compiling the regular expression during each run through my list. 

Set intersection was the third fastest, but the surprise came when checking the length of set and comparing to 0 was faster than simply transforming the intersection to boolean.

Comment: I'd suggest to use `re.escape` on the substrings before passing them to `re.compile`(i.e. `re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(sub) for sub in [...]))`), otherwise a substring that contains non-alphanumeric characters might create problems(it can even result in `re.compile` failing).

Comment: @Bakuriu, +1 for telling about `re.escape`.

Answer (score 0):

If your list of substrings is small and the input is small, then using a for loop to do compares is fine.

Otherwise the fastest way I know to search a string for a (large) list of substrings is to construct a DAWG of the word list and then iterate through the input string, keeping a list of DAWG traversals and registering the substrings at each successful traverse.

Another way is to add all the substrings to a hashtable and then hash every possible substring  (up to the length of the longest substring) as you traverse the input string.

It's been a while since I've worked in python, my memory of it is that it's slow to implement stuff in. To go the DAWG route, I would probably implement it as a native module and then use it from python (if possible). Otherwise, I'd do some speed checks to verify first but probably go the hashtable route since there are already high performance hashtables in python.

Comment: A link to a document on directed acyclic word graphs would probably be in order here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph